# MessageBox doesn't show the variable

Tags: c#

I have a list variable and I created an iterator for it to print out its content. It's working in the console application but when i try to do it using windows form(gui) it doesn't work

**PROGRAM.CS**

```
namespace gui
{
    static class Program
    {
        public class studentdata
        {
        public string id, name, password, academicyear, finishedcourseslist, ipcourseslist;
        public int noCoursesF, noCoursesIP;
        public List<string> coursesF;
        public List<string> coursesIP;
        public studentdata()
        {
            id = "2015123";
            password = "Student";
            coursesF = new List<string>();
            coursesIP = new List<string>();
        }

        public studentdata(string ID, string NAME, string PASSWORD)
        {
            id = ID;
        }

        **public void view_finished_courses()
        {
            List<string> finished = coursesF;
            foreach (string n in finished)
            {
                finishedcourseslist += n;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(finishedcourseslist, "Finished courses");
        }

        public void view_ip_courses()
        {
            List<string> progress = coursesIP;
            foreach (string m in progress)
            {
                ipcourseslist += m;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(ipcourseslist, "Finished courses");
        }**
    }

    public class Admin
    {
        public string name, password;

        public Admin()
        {
            name = "Admin";
            password = "Admin";
        }
    }

    //functionssssss
    internal static studentdata studentSearch(string IDsearch)
    {
        FileStream FS = new FileStream("Students.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);

        studentdata std = new studentdata();

        while (SR.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string z = SR.ReadLine();

            String[] Fields;
            Fields = z.Split(',');

            if (IDsearch.CompareTo(Fields[0]) == 0)
            {
                std.id = Fields[0];
                std.password = Fields[1];
                std.name = Fields[2];
                std.noCoursesF = int.Parse(Fields[3]);
                int currentField = 4;
                for (int course = 0; course < std.noCoursesF; course++)
                {
                    std.coursesF.Add(Fields[currentField]);

                    currentField++;
                }

                std.noCoursesIP = int.Parse(Fields[currentField]);
                currentField++;
                for (int course = 0; course < std.noCoursesIP; course++)
                {
                    std.coursesIP.Add(Fields[currentField]);
                    currentField++;
                }
                std.academicyear = Fields[currentField];

                SR.Close();
                return std;
            }
            else continue;
        }
        SR.Close();
        studentdata araf = new studentdata();
        return araf;
    }
}
```

**FORM.CS**

```
namespace gui
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        Program.studentdata student = new Program.studentdata();

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            student.view_finished_courses();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            student.view_ip_courses();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is an empty message box, I don't know why variable isn't added.

Comment: Did you debug to see what is coming in the variable?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should make sure you have a minimalist "working" version of your problem. This is to much text for us to "debug" for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace messagebox line with

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", coursesF.ToArray()), "Finished courses");
```

Comment: gives unhandled exception error .. even if i try with ToString

Comment: Sorry my bad use CourseF and the no need for for loop also

Comment: how come no need for foreach loop its the iterator which iterates the list

Comment: Because you are looping only to concatenate the contents of the collection into one string, this is what `string.Join` does, only with a delimiter.

Comment: If it's empty then your collection is empty. Put a breakpoint in code and inspect the collection elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code is incomplete. Nowhere in the code which gets executed after you clicked button4 you are adding items to coursesF. It seems that you are adding items in this line: `std.coursesF.Add(Fields[currentField]);`
This line is in your function `studentSearch(IDsearch)`, the function never gets called. 
In this function you got a string z in which all the data of a student is saved (`string z = SR.ReadLine()`). You must somehow fill this string z. You can use a TextBox in your form and pass the value into the string, use a string from a text file or use the console input(see here: [Get input from console into a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676872/get-input-from-console-into-a-form)).

As you can see the issue is not a one line fix.